# Jquery scroll to new postion when class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that changes a class upon navigation. Every time I click to the next page, the class `.active` changes to the actual page displayed.

In the code below the class is at the first anchor. When I move to the next page the class changes to the second anchor.

However, sometimes the menu becomes too big and scrolling is needed, as the navigation goes to the last pages the `.active` class is no longer viewed and the user needs to scroll down the menu to find out which page he is at.

I need that the when the class `.active` changes the scroll on the menu changes with it so the user doesn't need to scroll.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <a id="but-1" href="#" class="nav-link active">Livro </a>
  <a id="but-2" href="#" class="nav-link ">Melhorias</a>
  <a id="but-3" href="#" class="nav-link">Papel</a>
  <a id="but-4" href="#" class="nav-link">Melhor</a>
  <a id="but-5" href="#" class="nav-link ">Capcha n</a>
  <a id="but-6" href="#" class="nav-link ">Op</a>
  <a id="but-7" href="#" class="nav-link">Inclus</a>
  <a id="but-8" href="#" class="nav-link ">Lista d</a>
  <a id="but-9" href="#" class="nav-link ">Possibilidade</a>
  <a id="but-10" href="#" class="nav-link ">Possibilidade</a>
  <a id="but-11" href="#" class="nav-link ">Integra</a>
  <a id="but-12" href="#" class="nav-link ">Posi</a>
  <a id="but-13" href="#" class="nav-link ">Parametriza </a>
  <a id="but-14" href="#" class="nav-link ">Outros </a>
</ul>
```

Code that assigns the .active

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#but-1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "extra/SaibaLivroDayTrade.html", success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }
            });
            $("#but-1").addClass("active");
            $("#but-2").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-3").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-4").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-5").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-6").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-7").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-8").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-9").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-10").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-11").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-12").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-13").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-14").removeClass("active");
        });

        $("#but-2").click(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: "extra/MelhoriasTelaNegocios.html", success: function (result) {
                    $("#div1").html(result);
                }
            });
            $("#but-1").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-2").addClass("active");
            $("#but-3").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-4").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-5").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-6").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-7").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-8").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-9").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-10").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-11").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-12").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-13").removeClass("active");
            $("#but-14").removeClass("active");
        });
  });
```

Comment: where's the code that assigns the `.active` class?

Comment: I just added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is likely [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) even if it is not a jQuery feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $container = $("html,body");
var $scrollTo = $('.active');

$container.animate({scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top - $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop(), scrollLeft: 0},300);
```